# Is there a way to get the Facebook like count for a given Mailchimp campaign via the API?

Tags: mailchimp

I am building a custom statistics panel with the MailChimp API v1.3 and I can't find the Facebook likes total count for a campaign in the API. Is it 
available?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `campaignStats()` method to grab the number of Facebook Likes on your campaign.

```
 $campaignStats = $mailChimpAPI->campaignStats($campaignId);

 $facebookLikes = $campaignStats['facebook_likes'];
```